# Python : Comparing values between rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I want to find a pattern between rows and columns and thought that Panda might be useful but somehow I cannot index the output in Pandas. Its giving errors such as list out of range, data frame instructor wrongly called etc.I want to find a variation between rows say September 2018 and October 2018 or Feb 2019 and March 2019. Output at the end of the code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://quotes.ino.com/exchanges/contracts.html?r=NYMEX_NG"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
column_headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=3)[2].findAll('th')]

print(column_headers)
data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[3:]
for td in data_rows:
    Market = td.findAll('td')[0].text
    Contract = td.findAll('td')[1].text
    Open = td.findAll('td')[2].text
    High = td.findAll('td')[3].text
    Low = td.findAll('td')[4].text
    Last = td.findAll('td')[4].text
    Change = td.findAll('td')[4].text
    Pct = td.findAll('td')[4].text
    Time = td.findAll('td')[4].text

    print( Market, Contract, Open, High, Low, Last,Change, Pct, Time)
```

## Output

**Only Partial copied as this generates many lines**

---

```
 ['Market', 'Contract', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Last', 'Change', 'Pct', 'Time']
  NG.U18.E Sep 2018 (E) 2.958 2.960 2.945 2.945 2.945 2.945 2.945
  NG.V18.E Oct 2018 (E) 2.944 2.946 2.932 2.932 2.932 2.932 2.932
  NG.X18.E Nov 2018 (E) 2.975 2.977 2.964 2.964 2.964 2.964 2.964
  NG.Z18.E Dec 2018 (E) 3.068 3.071 3.058 3.058 3.058 3.058 3.058
  NG.F19.E Jan 2019 (E) 3.154 3.157 3.144 3.144 3.144 3.144 3.144
  NG.G19.E Feb 2019 (E) 3.117 3.118 3.110 3.110 3.110 3.110 3.110
  NG.H19.E Mar 2019 (E) 3.009 3.015 3.005 3.005 3.005 3.005 3.005
  NG.J19.E Apr 2019 (E) 2.698 2.698 2.698 2.698 2.698 2.698 2.698
  NG.K19.E May 2019 (E) 2.671 2.675 2.662 2.662 2.662 2.662 2.662
  NG.M19.E Jun 2019 (E) 2.697 2.701 2.692 2.692 2.692 2.692 2.692
  NG.N19.E Jul 2019 (E) 2.727 2.730 2.717 2.717 2.717 2.717 2.717
  NG.Q19.E Aug 2019 (E) 2.736 2.736 2.722 2.722 2.722 2.722 2.722
```

Comment: you're not using pandas.

Comment: Can you help here? I am doing the best I can.

Comment: Yes I fixed your code indentation. Cheers. It's still very unclear what your problem is. There are no errors in your code, and you're not doing anything with the `pandas` library at all.

Comment: Also I observe that you're pulling the same element text for each of `Low`, `Last`, `Change`, `Pct`, and `Time`. That looks like a mistake to me, since 5 elements can't possibly be represented by the same `td` element.

Comment: My question is I would like to index rows so that I can plot the rows and compare against one another on how much the price difference is between particular months. Or may be index columns to find a price variation. Can you help me on how to assign index using Pandas? I am new to Pandas / Python so I would take your advice if I am wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here's how to dump this into a `DataFrame`, example using only the first 10 rows of `data_rows`:

```
from pandas import DataFrame as DF

# the rest of your import statements...
# the rest of your code up until the `for td in data_rows` loop


table_data = [] # empty container for our table's data
for td in data_rows[:10]:
     table_data.append(list(e.text for e in td.findAll('td')))

# create the DataFrame:
df = DF(table_data, columns=column_headers)

print(df)
```

Outputs the following frame. What you do with it at this point is up to you.

```
     Market      Contract   Open   High    Low   Last  Change     Pct   Time
0  NG.U18.E  Sep 2018 (E)  2.958  2.960  2.945  2.955  -0.001  -0.03%  21:53
1  NG.V18.E  Oct 2018 (E)  2.944  2.946  2.932  2.943  -0.001  -0.03%  21:53
2  NG.X18.E  Nov 2018 (E)  2.975  2.977  2.964  2.974  -0.001  -0.03%  21:48
3  NG.Z18.E  Dec 2018 (E)  3.068  3.071  3.058  3.068  -0.001  -0.03%  21:48
4  NG.F19.E  Jan 2019 (E)  3.154  3.157  3.144  3.155  +0.001  +0.03%  21:32
5  NG.G19.E  Feb 2019 (E)  3.117  3.118  3.110  3.118   0.000   0.00%  19:36
6  NG.H19.E  Mar 2019 (E)  3.009  3.015  3.005  3.015  +0.001  +0.03%  19:36
7  NG.J19.E  Apr 2019 (E)  2.698  2.698  2.698  2.698  -0.007  -0.26%  18:13
8  NG.K19.E  May 2019 (E)  2.671  2.675  2.662  2.670  -0.003  -0.11%  16:02
9  NG.M19.E  Jun 2019 (E)  2.697  2.701  2.692  2.695  -0.004  -0.15%  15:26
```

Comment: Excellent. Send me your email. I want to send you gift card David. Have a coffee on me.

Comment: @SiddharthKulkarni there's no need to send me anything, but thank you! On Stack Overflow, the way to thank people for helpful answer is by voting up or marking answer as Accepted. Cheers.

Comment: One last question - Can you suggest a book on Python which could be helpful to me, at my knowledge level on web scraping and Panda? I have already have books on Data Analysis and Web Scraping by Ryan Mitchell but somehow cannot follow. I would like to have a book that teaches application specific Python.